# Why is it moth-er, but fa-ther?

Tags: hyphenation

I've googled around and haven't found a single good resource on hyphenation rules in English that explain why, for instance, it's moth-er, but fa-ther. Or Lat-in but cre-tin etc. etc.  Anyone with any advice?

Comment: What's your source for "moth-er" and "fa-ther" being the right hyphenations?

Comment: That's the only way I've ever seen it done. m-w. com agrees.

Comment: It depends a lot on the vowel. What resources on hyphenation have you looked at?

Comment: Maybe you'll find this discussion helpful? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346709/which-syllable-does-a-consonant-belong-to

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Not sure how helpful that is. It mentions a few general rules, but I don't think any of them would apply here. The consonant sound at the syllable boundary is the same, the only difference is the first syllable vowel.

Comment: The difference is that *mother* has a "short vowel" while *father* has a "long vowel" (these are also called "lax" and "tense" vowels; neither name is particularly illumninating).

Comment: I actually suspected it *may* be related to that, but I'm still looking for a resource that explains that that is actually the rule that determines how to hyphenate syllables.  It certainly seems to be typically be the case that short-vowel syllables are hyphenated with the hyphen after the consonants but long-vowel syllables with the hyphen after the vowel, but like I said, I haven't found any resource confirming that as a general rule.  The https://sarahsnippets.com/syllable-division-rules/ page is a good start, but some references to something a bit more "official" would be nice?